# How to set an arbitrary positional argument, while still preserving the rest?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to do something like this, but preserve every argument after `$i`:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    if [[ $i == "--" ]]; then
        set $i "-S --"
        break
    fi
done
ls "$@"
```

In this example, I want to make a simple wrapper over `ls` where `-S` is always the final option that is applied.

This is simple if the arguments do not have "--":

```
ls "$@" -S
```

However, this breaks whenever there is a "--" as an argument.

To work around this, I would like to find the first occurrence of `--` and place an  `-S` before it.

EDIT:

The reason why I do not use:

```
ls -S "$@"
```

is because I want the output to be sorted by size LAST. So if `-t` is passed into the arguments, the output should be sorted by modification time THEN by size. That use case fails here:

```
ls -S -t
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add `-S` at the beginning like that: `ls -S "$@"`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Does not work is $@ contains "-t". This would make it ls -S -t, which would sort by size THEN modification time. I want the output to always be sorted by size last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second array by iterating over the first one and inserting `-S` where needed.

```
#! /bin/bash
arr=()
for arg in "$@" ; do
    if [[ $arg == -- ]] ; then
        arr+=(-S --)
    else
        arr+=("$arg")
    fi
done

ls "${arr[@]}"
```

You might need to insert it just once to be utterly correct:

```
#! /bin/bash
arr=()
inserted=
for arg in "$@" ; do
    if [[ $arg == -- && ! $inserted ]] ; then
        arr+=(-S --)
        inserted=1
    else
        arr+=("$arg")
    fi
done
```

If you really need to set the positional arguments, use

```
set "${arr[@]}"
```

to set positional arguments to the members of ${arr[@]}.